# How can I change toc font when using abntex2 template?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, times, abnt

I am trying to change the font of my toc, I already searched a lot, and I found many ways, but it didn't work for me.

I want to change the actual font to Times New Roman.

Somebody could help me?

I am using `abntex2` template on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no example is given, I just loaded the `mathptmx` package for `Times` font and redefined the apparent class default `\sfdefault` to be `\rmdefault`.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault} % No serif fonts, use roman (times)
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @christian-hupfer thanks for your answer and sorry for no example. I had already tried only with `\usepackage{mathptmx}` and just the toc stay without Times New Roman, now when I add `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}` it works. Thank you so much

Comment: @ItaloPessoa: Yes, the `abntex2` class does something 'weird' there. It's quite difficult to read the documenation of that class since I don't understand Portuguese (apart from 'lua' ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer solved the problem with brutal force (that's ok since he can't read the manual) and if used will obliterate any sans serif font from the document. The proper way to deal with such customization of the `abntex2` class is through the formatting commands:

```
\ABNTEX<doc-division-name>font
\ABNTEX<doc-division-name>fontsize
```

Where `<doc-division-name>` is either: `part`, `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection` or `subsubsubsection`. Renewing this commands in the preamble will affect the whole document.

In regard of the ToC, it is formatted in accordance with the chapter style, therefore, changing the chapter style will change the ToC as well:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\textual
\chapter{Intero}
Blind text.
\end{document}
```

And finally, regarding the Times New Roman issue, there is another possibility which is to use the `fontspec` package, but for this to work the document must be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\textual
\chapter{Intero}
asd
\end{document}
```

Since sometimes (Lua/Xe)LaTeX can present a few issues, a flexible way is described within the `abntex2` manual, which can be compiled with either Pdf, Xe or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
  \else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{mathptmx}
\fi

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\textual
\chapter{Intero}
asd
\end{document}
```